# Website page loading very slow

Tags: dns, server, html, lookup, pagespeed

My webpage is taking too much time to load. In this screenshot you can see that it takes almost 26 secs before other resources starts to load. The first row is for the domain(mysite.com)

[image]

Can somebody please suggest, what may be the reason for this

EDIT1: I did a pingdom test and it seems that it is because of slow DNS lookup. Please see the image below. What can be the reason for this? The domain was more than 1 year old and was purchased on GoDaddy. Once  it expired this January, it was renewed. What is the issue here? Thanks for your help

[image: Pingdom Test]

Comment: Obviously something is blocking the page creation. This could be a javascript file, waiting for a cdn or other external site to respond. You image doesn't give the full picture.

Comment: From what I understand, the green bar represents the time it takes for the browser to get a reply from the server.

Comment: It's certainly some kind of blocking operation on your server. What kind of server are you using?

Comment: @PitaJ I am using apache2/ubuntu deployed on AWS

Comment: Your server is responding slow , Please check all images path is correct and also check if there is so many redirect in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be many reason behind that like (Network traffic , Server issue etc ). You can try below steps :-
1) Open your website on server where you have hosted. 
2) Check the application error in event log. 
3) enable profiling in your browser. 
4) Check the connectivity with you database.